# Changing Connection String (Dataset) before its Rendered on a Vb.Project

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, dataset, render

My purpose is I want to change the value of this Application Scope Connection String using Code. 
So, I have this dataset database for my vb.net project. and it's fully working 
(fully rendered) when we're running the app.

[image]

If you open the project setting, it is stored on Connection String.
It is using Applicatio Scope. Not user Scope. ANd it's
saved with its value ; *"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\ProgramData\RK-Medis\db-used.mdb"*

My questions are:

1. Can we change that variable value of Connection String before its
   called / rendered on its GUI?
2. WHat are the code for changing it?
3. If no we can't change it, then what are the alternative for using
   dataset + its Connection String that automatically used in almost
   many tables (GUI) i have...?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion of terms here that's making it difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use a different connection string when the app's deployed to the one that you're using during development/testing?  If so then you simply change the value of the connection string in the config file.

Comment: yes @jmcilhinney I want to change the value of the (app scope) Connection string via code

Comment: So, you want the user to be able to enter new connection properties and those be saved to the config file, or just for the current session?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a tableConnectionString for example, to store the CS for each user. Then use a property of string(or maybe const variable) to store your connection string for that particular user during user login. Substitude the CS to your application. Then each of the user will be able to have different CS.
Hope its give you the idea.